# suddenly my laptop keyboard and mouse pad are not working

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

I'm using a Toshiba laptop. I left my laptop for a while without shutdown, after some time when again I reopen my pc, I find out my laptop keyboard and mouse pad are not working. But my external mouse and in boot menu my laptop keyboard are working.

I apply the given below solution but it does not work.

Install the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

If already installed, reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

then Reboot.

Comment: Have you confirmed that "Slow Keys" is not enabled by accident?

Comment: 'slow keys' is disabled